# Variables in powershell - Adding variable to script

Tags: powershell

I am looking to write a script in PowerShell, however I want to set a variable and then have it fill the variable value in my script. To be more specific the variable I want to set is an IP address and I want to enter it into a script that pulls 3 files for me, as I manage a large number of computers. Here is an example of one file from the script that I want run:

```
Copy-Item -Path '\\VariableIwantToEnterIPaddress\C$\ComputerZ\log\File.log' -Destination C:\Users\JayZ\Desktop
```

Where I put `VariableIwantToEnterIPaddress` I would place a variable then have it fill as an IP address. Either setting the variable first then running the script. Or having PowerShell prompt me for a value then it run the script.

Is this possible, or is there a better method of doing this?

Comment: It's very possible, and I do it routinely. There's nothing special about the method to do it, either, and with just a little bit of reading about PowerShell, you can write your script to work in either of the two ways you describe, without change. However, [SO] is not a code-writing service; you'll need to show your work and ask a specific question before any detailed help will be offered.

Comment: I appreciate the comment - but it is written in this fashion for security and privacy policies that we are abiding to in our work environment. It is a hypothetical direct translation of the issue I am troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
$IPs = '10.10.0.1','10.10.0.2','10.10.0.3' #Enter your IP addresses here
foreach ($ip in $IPs) {
    Copy-Item "\\$($ip)\C$\ComputerZ\log\File.log" -Destination C:\Users\JayZ\Desktop
}
```

**Edit:** This should make it easier to enter in IP addresses, as many as you would like

```
function Copy-Files {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string]$ip
    )        
    process {
        Copy-Item "\\$($ip)\C$\ComputerZ\log\File.log" -Destination C:\Users\JayZ\Desktop
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
'10.10.0.1','10.10.0.2','10.10.0.3' | Copy-Files
```

Comment: Just an FYI, your subexpression `$()` is unnecessary in your use-case.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I know.  I just use it out of habit because I have had it burn me too many times in the past

Comment: A better way would be to use drive getters: `${}` which is equivalent to `$(Get-Content -Path Variable:varname)` and it delimits the variable call very clearly without being overly cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way, in my opinion, is to use the Read-Host cmdlet. Basically:

```
$ipaddr = Read-Host -Prompt 'IP:'
Copy-Item "\\$ipaddr\C$\ComputerZ\log\File.log" -Destination C:\Users\JayZ\Desktop
```

By using Read-Host and the string .Split, you could loop through several IPs like this:

```
$ipaddr = Read-Host -Prompt 'IP List:'
$iplist = ipaddr.Split(" ")
foreach ($ip in $iplist) {
    Copy-Item "\\$ip\C$\ComputerZ\log\File.log" -Destination C:\Users\JayZ\Desktop
}
```

Then you just type in the IP addresses with a space between them when you run the script.

Answer (score 0):

Use script parameters.

*MyScript.ps1*

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True, Position = 0)]
    [Alias('CN','IP')]
    [System.String[]]
    $ComputerName
)
ForEach ($CN in $ComputerName)
{
    Copy-Item -Path "\\$CN\C$\ComputerZ\log\File.log" -Destination C:\Users\JayZ\Desktop
}
```

The `[Parameter()]` attribute I've included forces the user to enter a CN/IP if omitted and allows you to not use named-parameters:

```
PS C:\> MyScript.ps1 127.0.0.1
```

or

```
PS C:\> MyScript.ps1 -ComputerName 127.0.0.1
```

When you omit:

```
PS C:\> MyScript.ps1

cmdlet MyScript at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
ComputerName: _
```

And lastly, to run against multiple PCs, use a comma-separated list:

```
PS C:\> MyScript.ps1 127.0.0.1, 168.5.3.2
```

Comment: This only does it for one IP or computername

Comment: @HeedfulCrayon And? OP didn't say he wanted to run it against multiple PCs at once, he just said he wants to copy multiple **_files_** at once.

Comment: OP: "To be more specific the variable I want to set is an IP address and I want to enter it into a script that pulls 3 files for me, as I manage a large number of computers"
Computers is multiple... meaning pass in multiple IP addresses to get one file from that computer

Comment: @HeedfulCrayon *Assuming* that was his intent, I've updated my answer to address that use-case